# Can't write generic function for shapless Generic

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I'm using [Generic](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala) in my DB layer to convert instances of case classes to `List[Any]` of JDBC-complaint types. Thus I have following pattern repeating all the time

```
val genSignal = LabelledGeneric[Signal]
genSignal.to(item).values.map(toSqlTypedHlist).toList
```

IntelliJ hints that `values` is unknown field but it compiles. So I decided to write following method

```
  private def getSqlValuesFromCaseClass[T <: AnyRef : Generic](item : T) : Seq[Any] = {
    val generic: Generic[T] = implicitly[Generic[T]]
    generic.to(item).values.map(toSqlTypedHlist).toList
  }
```

where `toSqlTypedHlist` is

```
private object toSqlTypedHlist extends Poly1 {
  implicit def atAnything[T: SqlTyped] = at[T](_.toSqlType)
}
```

but it fails to compile saying that

```
Error:(730, 22) value values is not a member of generic.Repr
    generic.to(item).values.map(toSqlTypedHlist).toList
                     ^
```

What am I missing here ?

UPD: I updated function to following per Miles' advice but it didn't help

```
 private def getSqlValuesFromCaseClass[T <: AnyRef : Generic](item : T) : Seq[Any] = {
  val generic: Generic[T] = implicitly[Generic[T]]
  generic.to(item).map(toSqlTypedHlist).toList
}
```

I get following error

```
Error:(73, 22) value map is not a member of generic.Repr
    generic.to(item).map(toSqlTypedHlist).toList
                     ^
```

Comment: Can you say what `toSqlTypedHlist` is? Is it a shapeless `Poly`?

Comment: @MilesSabin Pleasure to see you, Mike. `toSqlType` is function of implicit class: https://github.com/cppexpert/article-reader/blob/master/src/main/scala/co/kernelnetworks/medstream/server/db/package.scala#L21-L24

Comment: You've pointed me at `toSqlTyped` which is an ordinary Scala method. I need to see the definition of `toSqlTypedHList` which I think must be a shapeless `Poly` if that first fragment compiles.

Comment: Thanks. Is the switch from `LabelledGeneric` in the first example to `Generic` in the second intentional?

Comment: @MilesSabin Yes, but it was cosmetic change. I found out that there is `Generic.apply` with implicit and I thought it would be nice to use it instead of referring particular variable.

Comment: Well, it's responsible for the error, because the type `Repr` of `LabelledGeneric` is a shapeless record for which `.values` is defined, whereas the type `Repr` of `Generic` is a plain `HList` which doesn't support `.values`. So just drop the `values` in the second examples and you should be good.

Comment: @MilesSabin I can't  use `map` on `generic.to(item)`. Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Have you made the change from `LabelledGeneric` to `Generic` that I suggested, or otherwise modified the example? Either way, could you update the question to reflect where you've got to with the problem and I'll take it from there.

Comment: @MilesSabin But I don't use `LabelledGeneric` in `getSqlValuesFromCaseClass`. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of,

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper

private def getSqlValuesFromCaseClass[T, R <: HList](item: T)
  (implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[T, R],
    mpr: Mapper[toSqlTypedHlist.type, R]
  ): Seq[Any] = {
  gen.to(item).map(toSqlTypedHlist).runtimeList
}
```

What you were missing was the `Mapper` instance (indexed by both the `HList` representation type `R` and the singleton type of your `Poly`).

Note that the use of `runtimeList` loses all precision, as required by your result type signature of `Seq[Any]`, however this isn't idiomatic use of shapeless ... typically I would expect to see a precisely typed computation over the mapped elements or a fold of some sort.

Comment: Thanks! I get `value runtimeList is not a member of mpr.Out`  error with this version of function.

Comment: What version of shapeless are you using?

Comment: 2.2.5 (I can't post reply because it's too short thus I wrote this sentence)